# $C^1[0,1]$ is not complete with respect to sup norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I think the right sequence is $f_n(t)=|t-\frac{1}{2}|^{(n+1)/n}$ but I can't manage to prove it's Cauchy... (when I look at graph of $f_n$s it seems obvious, but I need it formal way.

Comment: Try finding $\lVert f_n - f\rVert_\infty$, where $f(t) = \lvert t-\frac{1}{2}\rvert$. That may be easier.

Comment: But I know $f_n(t)$ is Cauchy, so one must be able to prove it's really Cauchy. SO you propose alternative approach? Let $f_n$ remain unknown and find one that satisfies $\forall  \epsilon>0 \dots$

Comment: What Daniel Fischer means is that $f_n$ converges to $f$ in $C^0([0,1])$, so $f_n$ is necessarily Cauchy in $C^1([0,1])$.

Comment: Because every convergent sequence is Cauchy sequence, yes?

Comment: @DanielFischer I'm a bit puzzled -- the $f_n$ in the question involve an absolute value which is not differentiable at $0$. Is $f_n(t) = |t-1/2|^{(n+1)/n}$ really in $C^1$?

Comment: @MattN. Yes, $$\frac{d}{dx}\lvert x\rvert^{1+\varepsilon} = (1+\varepsilon)\operatorname{sign}(x)\cdot \lvert x\rvert^\varepsilon$$ is continuous for $\varepsilon > 0$.